# Persistent Docker Installation Issue on AMD Ryzen 7: Windows Hypervisor Platform and Hyper-V Feature Challenges

Tags: docker, powershell, installation

[image]

I made several attempts to download Docker on my AMD Ryzen 7-based PC. In order to accommodate the absence of the Hyper-V feature in Optional Features, I enabled the Windows Hypervisor Platform. Following this, I uninstalled Docker, rebooted my laptop, and proceeded with a fresh installation. Despite these efforts, when I tried to open Docker again, I was confronted with an error message that hindered its operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable virtualization for amd via bios and run it again